# pandoc "styles" extension not found

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, pandoc

I am using the `pandoc` `styles` extension for applying the custom style to the output word document using the rmarkdown.

It worked perfectly on my local machine. However, it's giving me an error  `styles extension not found` on the `r shiny pro server`.

Unfortunately, I don't have a permission to make any configuration changes at the `r shiny pro server`.

I would like to know if there is any way to load the extension from the application like the way we install the packages from the server.R?

Answer (score 2):

No, [pandoc extensions](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extensions) are part of the pandoc binary (which is not written in R, but is a single executable file, compiled from Haskell) and cannot be loaded like R packages.

You would need to update to a newer pandoc version that does have this extension.